# Can't find Traverse for sequencing Seq[ValidationNel[String, MyCaseClass]] => ValidationNel[String, Seq[MyCaseClass]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I have some code like the following:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class Foo(i: Int)
type ValidatedNel[A] = ValidationNel[String, A]

val foos: Seq[ValidatedNel[Foo]] = Seq(Success(Foo(1)), Success(Foo(2)), Failure(NonEmptyList("3 failed")), Failure(NonEmptyList("4 failed")))

val validated: ValidatedNel[Seq[Foo]] = foos.sequence[ValidatedNel, Foo]
```

This fails during compilation with this error:

> Error:(51, 50) could not find implicit value for parameter F0: scalaz.Traverse[Seq]
>       val validated: ValidatedNel[Seq[Foo]] = foos.sequence[ValidatedNel, Foo]
>
> Error:(51, 50) not enough arguments for method ToTraverseOps: (implicit F0: scalaz.Traverse[Seq])scalaz.syntax.TraverseOps[Seq,scalaz.package.ValidationNel[String,Foo]].
>   Unspecified value parameter F0.
>       val validated: ValidatedNel[Seq[Foo]] = foos.sequence[ValidatedNel, Foo]

I'd like to get an end result like this in the example I gave:

```
val validated = Failure(NonEmptyList("3 failed", "4 failed"))
```

If `foos` had only `Success` and no `Failure`, I'd like to see the simple sequence of them: `Success(Foo(1), Foo(2))`.

Why am I getting the compile failure I mentioned? As far as I understand it, this should work based on the types.

Is this related to the type aliasing unpacking to something like `A[B[C[D], E]] => B[C[D, A[E]]` instead of `A[B[C]] => B[A[C]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no instance of `Traverse[Seq]` in scalaz. You may replace the `Seq` by a `List` or convert it, or implement `Traverse[Seq]` (`implicit val seqInstance: Traverse[Seq] = ???`).

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class Foo(i: Int)
type ValidatedNel[A] = ValidationNel[String, A]

val foos: List[ValidatedNel[Foo]] = List(Success(Foo(1)), Success(Foo(2)), Failure(NonEmptyList("3 failed")), Failure(NonEmptyList("4 failed")))

val validated: ValidatedNel[List[Foo]] = foos.sequence[ValidatedNel, Foo]
```

Comment: Changing my `validated` type with List and adding `.toList` to the foos seq didn't help, it's the same error but with List where it was Seq before.

Comment: If you added the `toList` on the last line (`foos.toList.sequence(...)`), the compiler is looking for an implicit instance of `scalaz.Traverse[scala.List]`, which is provided by `scalaz.std.list.listInstance`. Which version of scalaz are you using?

Comment: I'm using scalaz 7.1.0 with scala 2.9.3. Importing listInstance makes it compile.